# xcode 4.2 iOS 5 and OAuth 2.0 - can you suggest a tutorial?

Tags: xcode, ios5, oauth-2.0

can you suggest a tutorial or detailed description how to obtain authorization with OAuth 2.0 for iOS 5. Or perhaps you can help me with starting point.

Comment: [OAuthConsumer](https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer/) usually does the trick for me. Dead simple, and pretty widely used.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to answer my question, hope it can help someone else. For OAuth 2 I found this solution:
http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

There are sample projects for mac and iOS.